# DAC to unity-gain buffer

Tags: operational-amplifier

I am trying to use a potentiometer with a capacitive supply and microcontroller. As digital-to-analog output current is too low, a buffer is needed. Buffer output is the Vcc at potentiometer. Problem is the supply, while [op-amp](https://www.mouser.com/datasheet/2/308/LM358-D-106278.pdf) is connected, supply voltage is 1.2V at most. From datasheet current draw is ~1mA, so that shouldn't be a reason for such high voltage drop on supply. What causes this behaviour ?
[image]

Comment: using a bjt as switch for op-amp supply, keeping it disconnected until voltage reaches normal level to power the mcu and DAC to function, then activate supply to op-amp, would be a solution ? my thought is 0v at non-inverted input causes the issue.

Comment: Could it have anything to do with applying 226V (\$160V\cdot \sqrt{2}\$) to the circuit and blowing something up?

Comment: @SvenB how is that even possible for this capacitive supply if zener will limit output to 5,1v ? i'm using Microchip's supply AN954, with larger capacitor, used to power PIC's from AC line, even 3.3V ones...

Comment: If D1 is forward biased, then C1 is charged to 226V, and D2 has to maintain a reverse voltage of 231V. Are these components rated for that? Did you also look at the currents?

Comment: @SvenB problem for this type of supply is no load, this why i use double wattage than calculated from equations. Tried cutting op-amp Vcc to measure current, but my multimeter isn't that sensitive. so, if opamp doesn't draw not even 10mA, how does the supply drops so much voltage ?

Comment: What I am trying to say is that your problem may not be the load, but the supply. I just checked the 1N4148 and it has a peak reverse voltage of 100V, while you are applying more than double that amount. Don't you think it'll break? Without D2, the output could never reach 5.1V as a working D2 is needed to charge C2.
I also do not advise working with these high voltages unless you know what you're doing. Would it not be possible to use a 5V adapter instead?

Comment: @SvenB , i've seen the 1n4148 in several 240Vac ST designs, anyway i'm using 1n4007 in real life. external supply is not an option for  current design. 1n4148 in dimmers http://www.st.com/content/ccc/resource/technical/document/application_note/95/52/c4/2c/12/2b/45/c1/CD00003820.pdf/files/CD00003820.pdf/jcr:content/translations/en.CD00003820.pdf    http://www.st.com/content/ccc/resource/technical/document/application_note/5a/fb/10/9b/98/20/4a/98/CD00003969.pdf/files/CD00003969.pdf/jcr:content/translations/en.CD00003969.pdf

Comment: Then I think we need more info/measurements. Maybe a component broke anyway, maybe the opamp is broken and shorts too much current to ground, maybe you accidentally put the potentiometer to 0% shorting the output, maybe there is a practical issue going wrong with your setup that can't be seen on the schematic, ...

Comment: @SvenB, just replaced all comps with new ones and as expected, same result. potentiometer is 22k, shouldn't be a problem for allowed 20mA output of the op-amp, for testing i left potentiometer output floating

Comment: How is your second OA connected ?

Comment: @Dorian no, left floating

Comment: Use a 5V supply to verify the circuit and see the current consumption. I checked the supply you use and should work. Send a picture, the setup is right, you must have missed something when you built the circuit.

Comment: @Dorian, please have a look. it's just so simple yet not working https://ibb.co/iNFcgT

Comment: Nothing unusual. The pot is not connected?

Comment: @Dorian right now, just disconnected the pot and the non-inverted input.....only left op-amp and supply. no go. input voltage 176Vac, output with amp 1.2V, without amp supply reaches 4.5V

Comment: I see it's a SMD , I suppose you remove the jumper when you see the voltage without the amp. Put a miliampermeter instead  of the jumper to see how much current is the amp drawing. That should give us a clue

Comment: yes i did, removed VCC pin of op amp, my multimeter current sensitivity is around 1-5mA, but displays nothing....i mean 0mA, this is what makes me so curios about so high voltage drop....

Comment: Then check R1 and C1. And D2 to , is the sense right?

Comment: All three must tolerate 1A mp current in the eventuality that the AC is connected starting with the peak voltage

Comment: @Dorian, i was about to give up, then decided to replace 1,5uF with another one as you said. Well, it seems X2 can fail.....or be faulty....now works perfect. If you want, post comment as answer. Thank you.

Comment: @SvenB You were right from the beginning, the high transitory current were the cause for the C1 fail.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Credits to @SvenB for being the first that pointed to the right direction.

Even on steady sinusoidal AC source the current through power supply components does not go higher than hundreds of milliampere when connecting the AC power the current might go up to 2 amps.

The worst case scenario is when the AC power was disconnected with C1 voltage at a maximum (+220V) and later connected while AC power was at a maximum opposite voltage (-225V).

This will put almost 450V on R1 , a peak current of 3A for a very short time (0.3ms).

**That's why components in the path R1, R6, C1, C2 D1 and D2 must tolerate a peak 3 amps current**

Tough, the continuous current might be as low as few hundreds mA.

From the comments it shows that C1 was dead first but any other could fail, usually the diodes and unpolarized capacitors get shorted, and the resistors are interrupted or their resistance grows. This time C1 capacity was altered to a lower value.

Don't forget to add a discharge resistor ( ~100k ) in parallel with the AC input to protect the operator from the remaining C1 voltage